# When Using React Native, how do you save the results of a fetch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, react-native, fetch

I am currently in the process of writing an Android React Native app powered by a JSON api served via a Ruby on Rails server. My biggest snag currently has been saving the results of a `fetch` call. My code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';

class MiniMinionClient extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  getStatus() {
    return fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/v1/status.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        return responseJson;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    var status = this.getStatus()
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Version {status.version}</Text>
        <Text>Last Update: {status.last_update}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MiniMinionClient', () => MiniMinionClient);
```

I do know this is a valid endpoint, as I was able to make the same call work if I use alert posts, which I got the idea from [here](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/09/make-http-requests-in-ios-with-react-native/). I think the issue stems from the asynchronous nature of `fetch` but I am not sure how to get around this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the output of `responseJson` or the data of the json file? I can provide you the full working code if I know the format .

Comment: The value coming back as a result of the function is a Promise object, and the data of the json file is 

{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "last_update": "07/27/2016 at 06:15AM"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the way to save and access the result of your api calls. The best way to call your api is from **componentWillMount** lifecycle. This lifecycle is called just before the Component is rendered.

You can either use your api call directly on **componentWillMount()** or call the getStatus() function you created.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';

class MiniMinionClient extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Initialize empty state here
    this.state = {
      version: '',
      last_update: ''
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    // It's best to use your api call on componentWillMount
    this.getStatus();
  }

  getStatus() {
     fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/v1/status.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        // set the state of the output here
        this.setState({
          version: responseJson.version,
          last_update: responseJson.last_update
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      {/*You can now access the values using this.state here*/}
        <Text>Version {this.state.version}</Text>
        <Text>Last Update: {this.state.last_update}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MiniMinionClient', () => MiniMinionClient);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick. My lack of experience with JS, Async, and React Native is making this a tad challenging. I appreciate your support.

Comment: While doing more research, I came upon this post as well [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37035423/react-native-fetch-api-not-returning-my-calls).

This one uses componentDidMount() versus componentWillMount(), are these the same, or do they provide different benefits?

Comment: You should learn more about **React Lifecycle**. This is one of the most important topic that you must be aware of.
There's difference between these two:
**componentWillMount** is executed before rendering, on both server and client side.
**componentDidMount** is executed after first render only on the client side. 
These links are helpful: http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2014/09/13/execution-sequence-of-a-react-components-lifecycle-methods/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_component_life_cycle.htm

Comment: componentWillMount is good for this but i am facing the same issue and i am making a login page, so i want to call fetch on the press of a button and then store the user's details in a React.useState(). How do I go about it ??